# To prove, that Bernoulli shift is sensitive to initial conditions

Tags: dynamical-systems, stability-theory

I have a following function:

$$
B(x) = 2x\bmod 1\\
x \in \left<0; 1\right)
$$

How could I prove, that this function is sensitive to initial conditions? I know it has something to do with Lyapunov exponent, but I only know following formula, which is used for discrete systems:

$$
\lambda(x_0) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum^{n-1}_{i=0} \ln \left| f'(x_i) \right|
$$

But, as far as I know, it's not useful here, because this problem is defined on a continuous domain.

How can I prove this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $x$ in binary form:
$$
x=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{a_k}{2^k},\quad x_k=0\text{ or }1.
$$
Identify $x$ with the sequence $(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots)$. Then
$$
B(x)=(x_2,x_3,\dots).
$$
Now let $x$ and $y$ be two very close numbers; say that their first $n$ binary digits are the same, and that $x_{n+1}\ne y_{n+1}$. Then the firs binary digit of $B^n(x)$ and $B^n(y)$ are different.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'm sorry, but I have one more question - how could I write e.g. \frac{1}{2} in binary form according to your formula? To be honest I don't quite understand, what are those $a_k$ variables.

Comment: The $x_k$ are the binary digits.$$\frac12=0,1000\dots=0,0111\dots,$$ the same way in base $10$ we have $$\frac1{10}=0,100\dots=0,0999\dots$$.